# The merging operation is not symmetric on its inputs in surface code as it should naturally be

Tags: error-correction, surface-code

My misunderstanding is probably due to a trivial thing I am not seeing.

In lattice surgery for surface code, we can perform a merging operation. This operation should be symmetric as indicated on Eq.5 in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.4022v3.pdf) paper, or Eq on top of page 5 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.05208.pdf) one (and it is a natural consequences of the sequences of operation you perform on the surface).

More precisely, for a rough merge, calling the two states to be merged:

$$|\psi\rangle= \alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1 \rangle $$
$$|\phi\rangle= \alpha' |0\rangle + \beta' |1 \rangle $$

The merging operation acts on the logical space as:

$$|\psi\rangle \otimes |\phi\rangle \to \alpha |\phi \rangle + (-1)^M \beta X |\phi\rangle$$

We see that within the process, a two qubit state is mapped to a single qubit state: the merging operation does not preserve the dimensions. As far as I understand, the "net" process is somewhat equivalent to measure the $X_1 X_2$ observable of the two qubit state and to map the result to a single qubit state. The quantity $M$ is the measurement outcome of the observable $X_1 X_2$ on the initial two qubit state.

By construction, the merging operation is symmetric, hence, by exchanging the role of $|\phi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle$, we expect to have (as indicated in the papers provided):

$$ \alpha |\phi \rangle + (-1)^M \beta X |\phi\rangle=\alpha' |\psi \rangle + (-1)^M \beta' X |\psi\rangle $$

However, if you do the calculation you realize that this last equality is not true. Below is a short script illustrating the issue

[image]

How to make sense of this? On one hand I agree with the paper that we should have the equality true (because we are merging two different surface into a single one: the process should be the same if we exchanged the initial two surfaces). But on the other hand the concrete calculation indicates that it is not the case (and is then in contradiction with the papers).

Comment: Why is there no $\psi$ term in your merging-result equation, and why is the flipped state only using one Pauli instead of the product of the pair of Paulis you're measuring?

Comment: @CraigGidney thanks for the comment. I am not sure to see what you mean though. I wrote the resulting ket of a merging operation using its definition from the papers. What this code tells me is that $|\psi \rangle M |\phi\rangle - |\phi \rangle M |\psi \rangle = ((-1)^M-1) (\alpha' \beta - \alpha \beta') |1\rangle \neq 0$ (where $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ are defined in my main text, and where $M$ denotes the merging operation). Hence the merging operation is not symmetric on its input and the equalities provided in the paper are not true. But I guess I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: (of course the $M$ in $(-1)^M$ represents the measurement outcome of $X_1 X_2$, while the $M$ in $|\psi\rangle M |\phi \rangle$ and in $|\phi\rangle M |\psi \rangle$ represent the merging operation, I should have taken two different letters in my previous comment but I am unable to edit now)

Comment: I guess what I'm confused about is how why your equation is sending a four dimensional state vector to a two dimensional state vector. XX parity measurement is a two qubit operation that preserves the dimensionality of the state space. How did you get rid of the tensor product?

Comment: @CraigGidney The merging operation consists in taking two separate surfaces and to merge them into a single one. Within this process we will then have two logical qubits that will be mapped to a single logical qubit state: this is an operation that does not preserve the dimensions.

Comment: The process does not simply consists in measuring an $XX$ observable but as far as I understand it, it is somewhat equivalent to measure an $XX$ observable, followed by mapping the resulting state to a single qubit state. This is why I talked about $XX$ measurement in my text (I edited to clarify this)

Comment: Reducing to a single qubit state is not a normal part of the definition of the XX measurement, in the same way that reducing to a 0 qubit state is not a normal part of the definition of the X measurement. And I suspect your asymmetry is coming from the reducing part, since when you reduce you have to pick one of the two possible single qubit Z observables to pair with the XX observable you're definitely keeping.

Comment: @CraigGidney I agree with you that in general, we don't lose a dimension by measuring. However lattice merging is not "just" measuring an observable. You can look at the page (8) of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.4022v3.pdf to see the full process in action. Physically it corresponds to merge two surfaces that are encoding a logical qubit in a unique surface: it "eats" two qubits and provides a single one. But this operation is somehow equivalent as first: measuring $XX$, then from this two qubit result we do the mapping:

Comment: $(|00\rangle+(-1)^M|11\rangle)/\sqrt{2} \to |0_L\rangle $, and $ (|01\rangle+(-1)^M|10\rangle)/\sqrt{2} \to |1_L\rangle$ where $M$ is the outcome of the $XX$ observable. The two qubit states I wrote in this mapping are, as you can see, spanning the eigenspace of $XX$ for the eigenvalue $(-1)^M$

Comment: The difference you're seeing is almost certainly due to different but equivalent-up-to-stabilizers-that-are-present choices which go away once you split again. For example, you may be focusing on either the (XI, ZZ) or to the (IX, ZZ) observable pairs as the "single qubit". Although XI is different from IX, they differ by what you measured (XX) so it's irrelevant which you pick; they can at most differ in sign and you will correctly account for this difference when splitting again.

Comment: @CraigGidney I'm not sure to follow. The first thing that confuses me is that geometrically speaking (if you look at the physical surfaces) the situation is *exactly* symmetric as we are merging two identical surfaces. Hence the process should be an operation that yields *exactly* to the same final logical state. Then, as we reason on the logical level, we cannot see any difference due to a product of stabilizers (as they yield a logical identity and can't be seen on the logical level).  Do you see what I mean?

Comment: when you reduce to a single logical qubit, where specifically is the single X observable located? It has to source from either the left side or the right side. You have to pick. That's the asymmetry you're seeing. But both choices are equivalent up to sign because you just measured the difference between those two choices; the XX observable.

Comment: @CraigGidney good observation! I will think about it more carefully and see if it solves the issues. I keep you updated.

Comment: @CraigGidney I am back on this question. My observations are the following. (i) The fact that the merging operation is not symmetric indeed seems related to the two possible choices to define $X_L$. If I look at the evolution of computational states in the $(+/-)$ logical basis, for $M=0$ there is a unique mapping possible ($|++\rangle \to |+\rangle$, $|-- \rangle \to |-\rangle$, but for $M=1$ depending on if I choose the logical $X$ of the new "full surface" to be on the left or on the right, I can map $|+- \rangle \to |-\rangle$, and $|-+ \rangle \to |+\rangle$ **or the opposite**

Comment: This is consistent with the fact I did not agree on the equivalence of the equations **only** for $M=1$. Now, this does not completely solve my issue. In Horsman's paper, they do a reasoning that does not make this subjectivity appear. Basically, they notice that $Z_L=Z_L^1 Z_L^2$ (where $Z_L$ is the logical $Z$ of the merged surface, and $Z_L^1,Z_L^2$ are the logical $Z$ of the half surfaces before merging). Based on that, they have a **unique** way to define the merging operation (which corresponds to the first equation I wrote)

Comment: @CraigGidney It leads me to my question: (ii) in their reasoning with the logical $Z$, where do they make a subjective choice in defining the merging procedure? I don't see it and it is necessary to have the global vision being consistent (i.e. you have two ways of defining the merging operation, but as long as you are consistant with the definition you took there is no issue).

Comment: $Z_L^1 Z_L^2$ is definitely wrong for a Z parity measurement, because that's a stabilizer of the patch, not an observable. If you're still talking about an X parity measurement then yeah, the observable you didn't measure is dealt with differently than the observable you measured. Why would X and Z be dealt with in the same way, given the different commutation restrictions?

Comment: @CraigGidney I am considering a rough merge in this discussion. $X_L^1 X_L^2$ would be a stabilizer (after merging). Not $Z_L^1 Z_L^2$ which is crossing the entire (merged) surface. I am not understanding the rest of your message. We can reason on any basis to understand the procedure. What I meant is that for a rough merge, I totally see that there is some ambiguity on the choice of $X_L$ for the post-merge surface (and it could lead to two ways to define the post-merge state). If you reason in the computational basis (as done in Horsman's paper), you define the logical state based on [...]

Comment: $Z_L \equiv Z_L^1 Z_L^2$. And there is no ambiguity on that choice (as opposed to the $X_L$). With that choice we uniquely define the $|0_L\rangle$ and $|1_L\rangle$ while there would have two choices for   $|+_L\rangle$ and $|-_L\rangle$ depending if $X_L=X_L^1$ or $X_L=X_L^2$. Hence depending on if I reason on the computational or $+/-$ basis I don't end up to the same conclusion. This is what disturbs me. We have some "convention" to take in the $+/-$ basis (leading to the two inequivalent expression of the merging operation), but not in the $0/1$ basis. This is weird.

Comment: I guess my advice is to stop being bothered by it because your intuition that it should be beautifully perfectly symmetric is simply wrong.

Comment: I am not saying that it should be symmetric (at least, I am no longer saying it in the comments). I am saying that the conclusion we get should not depend on the basis we reason with. In Horsman's paper, they reason with the $Z$ basis (why not). In this case, for a given value of the measurement of $X_L^1 X_L^2$, they find a unique mapping as indicated in Eqs (4). Hence, I don't see how the second expression for the merging (the one I give at the end of my main post) can occur when we reason on this basis. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @CraigGidney I think your POV here is essentially correct (the difference comes down to how you define the merged logical operators) but I would still say the Horseman et al paper has an error, since they define their merged logical operators in a specific way, but still claim the merge operation is symmetric. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is essentially the same as what Craig Gidney was hinting at in the comments. But perhaps you'll find the more explicit version more satisfying!

---

This is an interesting point! And it is a little disappointing that the papers  you cited gloss over it. I'll refer to the Horseman paper to give the answer. Their equation (2) says that after the merge, the state of the system is given by
$$
(\alpha\alpha'+ \beta\beta'
)(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)+(\alpha\beta'+ \beta\alpha'
)(|01\rangle + |10\rangle), \qquad M=1
$$
$$
(\alpha\alpha'- \beta\beta'
)(|00\rangle - |11\rangle)+(\alpha\beta'- \beta\alpha'
)(|01\rangle - |10\rangle), \qquad M=-1
$$
They then say that after the merge, we'll have a single logical degree of freedom, spanned by $(|00\rangle+M|11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ and $(|01\rangle+M|10\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. As a result, we can define the merged qubit logical states to be
$$
|0\rangle:=\frac{|00\rangle+M|11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
$$
|1\rangle:=\frac{|01\rangle+M|10\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
in which case, simple algebra gives that the state after the merge is $\alpha|\phi\rangle+\beta X|\phi\rangle$.

Now, you want to switch the roles of qubits $1$ and $2$ (and thus switch the roles of $\phi$ and $\psi$). This should definitely work! But to make this work, you have to:

- Swap $\alpha\leftrightarrow\alpha'$ and $\beta\leftrightarrow\beta'$.
- **Swap the two qubits in the definition of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$**

If you don't do the second step, you haven't really interchanged the role of the two qubits. When we defined $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, we arbitrarily chose one of our qubits to be the "first" qubit. We have to reverse this choice to get the correct answer when swapping the role of the two qubits.

Note that the definition of $|0\rangle$ is symmetric in the two qubits, but we should modify our definition of $|1\rangle$ as

$$
|1\rangle_{\mathrm{new}} :=\frac{|10\rangle+M|01\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}=M|1\rangle_{\mathrm{old}}
$$
which seems to be what you found in your Mathematica script.

---

As a punchline: You are correct that Eq. (5) of the original Horseman et al paper is not correct when it swaps the role of $\psi$ and $\phi$, because it doesn't change their definition of $|1\rangle$ accordingly.

Comment: Hey. Thank you for your answer. I am back on this topic in a few days and I give you a feedback =)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you agree with me if I say that in order to "land on our feet" by exchanging the role of the two surfaces, we must (i) swap the states $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi \rangle$ (your first bullet point), and (ii) take the "other convention" to define $X_L$. If before we had $X_L=X_L^2$ we need to change it to $X_L=X_L^1$. This last statement is equivalent to your second bullet point where you change the definition of $|1\rangle_{\text{new}} \to M |1\rangle_{\text{old}}$.

Comment: A related question. Do you agree with me that Splitting then Merging two surfaces (I assume both are of "rough" type for instance) is the same as doing an identity operation. However Merging then Splitting is irreversible (hence not equal to identity).

Comment: @StarBuck I agree with both of your points.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! (I cannot provide the bounty now I have to wait 24 hours). I will at that time.